# how they got such a transfer function?

Tags: control-theory, pi-controller

[image]

Could anyone explain to me the paragraph? How they have defined the $PI$ controller in discrete-time and how they got such a transfer function? and why the matrix will not be Schur? Thanks.

Comment: Is this really a math question? You were obliged to create 2 new tags for your question that are not math related...

Comment: At least this is wrong! *in a blog which no one sees except you.* http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/visitors/

Comment: what do you mean by this is wrong?your bogus link was for advertisement for the blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Part:** Discrete formulation of PI-Controller:
The continuous Laplace transform of a PI-Controller is given by

$$C(s) = \dfrac{\pi(s)}{e(s)}=k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}\dfrac{1}{s}$$
$$s\pi(s)=k_\text{P}se(s)+k_\text{I}e(s)$$

this implies the differential equation

$$\dot{\pi}(t)=k_\text{P}\dot{e}(t)+k_\text{I}e(t)$$

Now, apply the Euler Approximation for the derivative

$$\dot{x}(t)\approx \dfrac{x(k)-x(k-1)}{T_\text{S}},$$
in which $T_\text{S}$ is the sampling time.

$$\implies \pi(k)=\pi(k-1)+k_\text{P}e(k)-k_\text{P}e(k-1)+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}e(k)$$
$$\implies \pi(k)=\pi(k-1)+\left(k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}\right)e(k)-k_\text{P}e(k-1)$$
$$\implies \pi(k)=\pi(k-1)+\left(k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}\right)\left[e(k)-\dfrac{k_\text{P}}{k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}}e(k-1)\right]$$

Substituting $\kappa = k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}$ and $\alpha=\dfrac{k_\text{P}}{k_\text{P}+k_\text{I}T_\text{S}}$ results in the form that was given.

**2. Part:** Determining the $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform:
There are rules for getting the $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform of expressions like $f(k) \leftarrow f(z)$ and $f(k-1) \implies f(z)/z$ (Shifting rule). If you apply these rules to equation $(9)$ you will obtain equation $(10)$.

$$\pi(z)=\dfrac{\pi(z)}{z}+\kappa\left[e(z)-\alpha\dfrac{e(z)}{z} \right]$$

$$\implies \pi(z)\left[1-z^{-1} \right]=\kappa e(z)\left[1-\alpha z^{-1} \right]$$

$$C(z)=\dfrac{\pi(z)}{e(z)}=\kappa\dfrac{1-\alpha z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}.$$

**3. Part:** For the last part of the question ... I must admit that I don't know what the Schur property implies. But I guess that there is some theorem which implies the statement in the question. A matrix is Schur iff  absolute value of  eigenvalues are strictly less than one.

Comment: The Schur property has to do with the state space realization of the transfer function. Namely if all the eigenvalues of the system matrix ($A$) lie inside (not on) the unit circle it is said to be Schur. This is the discrete equivalent of the Hurwitz property for continuous systems, which requires all eigenvalues to lie in the left half plane. The Schur property is equivalent to saying that all poles need to lie inside the unit circle. Also see [stable polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_polynomial), where for matrices the polynomial is its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.